# Rubymine and Ruby namespaces, Expected: ; or end of line

Tags: ruby, rubymine

```
RubyMine 2016.3.1
Build #RM-163.9166.34, built on December 15, 2016
...
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

If I create this class:

```
class Account::User
end
```

Rubymine lint an error `Expected: ; or end of line` at first colon.

It's a rubymine bug?

Comment: _"...at first semicolon"_ – your code does not contain a semicolon.

Comment: is not duplicated question, I'm not working on a Mac and sorry @Stefan it's at first colon